# Why did Jesus call Herod 'that fox'?

Tags: luke, metaphor, apocrypha

Luke 13:31-32 KJV

> <sup>**31**</sup> The same day there came certain of the Pharisees, saying unto him, Get thee out, and depart hence: for Herod will kill thee. <sup>**32**</sup> And he said unto them, Go ye, and tell **that fox**, Behold, I cast out devils, and I do cures to day and to morrow, and the third day I shall be perfected.

In day-to-day language, fox is a metaphor for cunningness, stealth, and crookedness, whereas wolf is associated with cold-heartedness and murderous instinct. In the case of John the Baptist,  Herod had him killed as a wolf would its prey. Keeping of his brother's wife  as his own was also publicly known, on account of which the Baptist had reprimanded him.  Obviously, there were some characteristics of Herod that are not recorded in the Gospels; characteristics that would justify  his being called a fox.
So, Why did Jesus refer to Herod as 'that fox'?   Are there some apocryphal writings on the issue ?

Comment: Thanks, Dottard. I would be interested in apocryphal writings on the issue.

Comment: the article that Dottard mentioned has good answers. This one is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The fox was an [unclean](https://www.biblestudy.org/cleanfood.html) animal to the Jews.

So, Jesus was saying Herod was unclean.

At the same time, a fox is a cunning animal, which in this case was Herod's plan to kill Jesus, but Jesus clarified that He is in control.